# I have a question with Swift about the correct way closing views Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I have several views and I use this code to open and close them, so I move through all of them.

```swift
let viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController")
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(viewController,animated: true, completion:nil)
```

[image]

My question is: Am I really closing them or just opening one over another wasting memory?

So after reading the wise advise I've made same chnages but I have a last question about this point,I start my app int View1, and later have to move to View2 and from there to View 3. When I’ve realized that when I’m in View 3, I have open View1, View2 and of course View 3 so to fix it when I jump from View1 to View2 , firstly I close View1 with pop and later open View2 with pop. And when I want to return to View3 I use
To move from View1 to View2

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "View2")
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)    
    }
```

To return to View3 to View1 I use:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Is it correct to do a pop and a push in the same View ?

Comment: The code you posted creates a new view controller and displays it.  That code makes no attempt to dismiss any existing view controllers.

Comment: You've shown your `self.present(...)` code... do you have corresponding `dismiss(...)` code?

Comment: No i dont have any dsimiss because If I dismiss a view It returns to the previous Windows but I need to jump to a specifi view. For instance the fisr one without use segues and I dont know how to

Comment: Most apps manage a "stack" of views, presenting one over the other as the user navigates around the app. It is unusual to present a series of view controllers modally.  You typically use a navigation controller or a tab bar controller to help you.

Comment: What should I use to stack and avoid modals?

Comment: @Monrac - as **Paulw11** said, use a `UINavigationController`

Comment: Keep in mind that even with a navigation controller you still need to dismiss (pop) controllers as needed. You don’t want to keep pushing more and more or you will have the same issue you have now.

Comment: I've changed my code to:

         let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "AuthViewController")
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
So I only have one inflate view at the same. I think that now I'm doing it corretly, is that so?

Comment: Now you have two. The original and the one you just pushed.

Comment: Sorry... I feel I m losing something. My idea is start from the first view and use only a navigation bar. It seems I have two views open all the time. The main view and when I press a button the navigation bar opens another on top of that. Is that the correct way of doing it? Or do I have to dismiss the first view? And id I have to close the first one how I do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using a navigation view, it is normal to have the main as the root and then push on a view to navigate to it.  The back button would do a pop (and so dismiss the 2nd one) and show the main again.  But you can set the stack to whatever you want (a different root, or a different stack -- by just setting the navigationController's viewControllers array -- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621873-viewcontrollers)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing yourself and getting worried over the idea that *"Do I have two views open at the same time?"*

This is a very common way to use a Navigation Controller:

[image]

The "Go Next" buttons ***push*** the next controller onto the navigation "stack." You automatically get a "< Back" button on the navigation bar. If your controllers have Titles, the word "Back" will be replaced with the previous controller's Title.

So, at each "step" the user can:

- tap "Go Next" to go to the next "step"
- tap "Back" to go back one step

If I want to let the user go "Back to Start" ... I can, for example, add a button that would call `navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`

You don't need to worry about having "multiple views open." This is how Navigation Controllers work.